# No hay conexion a mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

El problema es el siguiente no encuentro el error que tengo para la conexión a mi base de datos, ya que ni siquiera ejecuta el código, ni me sale ningún mensaje de error.
Este código ya lo había usado antes pero ahora no funciona.

```
<?php
class Conexion{
    public static function Conectar() {
        define('servidor','localhost');
        define('nombre_db','xx');
        define('usuario','root');
        define('password','');

        $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
        
        try{
            $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".servidor.";dbname=".nombre_db, usuario, password,$opciones);                
            return $conexion;

            
        }catch(Exeption $e){
            die("El error de conexion es:" .$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Es una clase, ¿ya la ejecutas?  Es decir, debes escribir en alguna parte esto: `$conex = new Conexion()->Conectar();` y quizás entonces te muestre algun error.  Una clase de por si no hace nada si no la invocas de algun modo.

Comment: Estás creando una variable `$conexion` que solo está visible en el método estático `Conectar()` y no devuelves valor. Se puede suponer que el código se ejecuta, pero no te permite acceder a la conexión fuera de ese método.